# Categorizing data in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, categories

I have a dataframe named AH, with columns F1 and F2:

```
F1      F2
aq      ab
ac      my
```

(and so on)

I wanted to make another column and classify  each column first so it will become:

```
F1  Category1    F2    Category2
aq     77        ab     11
ac     77        my     55
```

The data are preprocessed already and I have made this code:

```
for len in range (AH):

    if AH ['F1'] =={'aq','ac'}:
        AH.loc[index, 'Category1'] = '77'
    elif AH ['F2'] =={'ab'}:
        AH.loc[index, 'Category1'] = '11'
    elif AH ['F2'] =={'my'}:
        AH.loc[index, 'Category1'] = '55'
   else:
        'NaN'
```

However, the error showed:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Anyone who can answer?

Comment: `range()` function takes integer as input and you are giving the `dataframe (AH)` as input which is why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function which you can call for each value of the column (F1 and F2)
as below:

```
def fun(x):
    if x is None:
        return ""
    if x in ['aq','ac']:
        return "77"
    if x in ['ab']:
        return "11"
    if x in ['my']:
        return "55"
#calling fun() for each value of F1 column and F2 column        
AH['Category1']=[fun(x) for x in AH.F1.values]
AH['Category2']=[fun(x) for x in AH.F2.values]
```